# Spring boot application run failed and the error is not clear

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

this is what I get when I start the spring project I downloaded. I tried some answers I found online but nothing helped.

```
15:58:19.132 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/build/ADH/NoteIt/noteit-api/target/classes/]
15:58:20.301 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at rc.noteit.NoteItApplication.main(NoteItApplication.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My pom.xml looks like this:
(I added myself the spring-boot-devtools dependency because it was missing and that caused errors. The rest was already there as I just cloned this project from another guy.)

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>noteitservice</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The error is quite clear. It cannot find classes, which means you have messed up your dependencies. Either you are cobling things together yourself instead of using the Spring Boot starters or you are mixing jars from different versions of spring (boot).

Comment: It's quite clear, sir...can you post (just the dependencies part of) your `pom.xml` or Gradle build script? The reason for `NoClassDefFoundError` is that a class is not available at runtime but was available during compile time.

Comment: I updated the question and added my pom.xml. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you set a version on the spring-boot-starter-mail dependency?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks for your comment. I'm really new to spring boot (just started learning it today) and this project is just an example I downloaded to understand how things work and not self written. so I don't know why the original programmer set a version on that dependency!

Comment: Try to remove this

Comment: Don't copy everything from a bolg, please refer the spring.io for project set up and it's common that version and dependencies used earlier now supported in different way. Everything is changing spring boot version their support for different starters.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the spring boot, the default parent dependencies may not be compatible with your dependencies like the devtools, so caused missing libraries

try a different version of spring boot that is compatible with your version of devtools, or remove the version of devtools to use the default one.
or add the missed dependency, here it cannot find the class LogMessage inside your version of org.springframework.core dependency,

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this instead:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- no need to declare spring-boot-starter-mail again -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- no need to import spring-boot-starter-tomcat since -web will do it -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It's nothing more than a simplified version of what you posted, without the version(s) and some other dependencies deleted since they are imported transitively. I'm not entirely sure if you need also `javax.xml.bind`, you can try deleting it also.